# create liquibase changeset validation rules

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

How can I create liquibase changeset custom rules?

**The Problem**

I want to make rules in my team, in which people don't do dangerous change on liquibase without knowing. I consider the dangerous things, specially things that make the database unusable to the old version of the application, making a rollback impossible.

**Solution I thought**
Create a custom rule to validate the changesets, in which we forbid changes like:
dropColumn, delete, dropTable, renameColumn

All these changes would break the build on maven, except if there is a comment on the same changeset with something like "i know what i'm doing".

**The Question**

Does liquibase offer any extension point where I can create this rule?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered introducing code reviews instead? On the other hand if your goal is not to forbid using `dropColumn`, but to annotate it to make sure that developer knows what he/she is doing then you could introduce two interfaces e.g. `BackwardCompatibleLiquibase` and `BackwardIncompatibleLiquibase` - first interface would contain the 'safe' methods and the other would contain all of them.

IMHO it's better to educate people within your team how to make changes that won't break the DB instead of introducing changeset validator, because if no one reviews the changesets then there's a chance that people will hack your validator or add the example comment 'i know what i'm doing' to every change set so the build will always pass

Comment: We have code reviews in place. This would be a safeguard tool, and education also.  The idea when things go wrong is error, explaining the risks of the change.

Comment: I forgot that liquibase' changesets are written in XML, not the java code. Then have a look at possible liquibase extensions: https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/2424879/Overview However IMHO you should educate your team on code reviews